# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn') on Vite with AdminLTE

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vite, adminlte

My Laravel 10 projects uses AdminLTE as his theme, jQuery and Bootstrap.
jQuery and Bootstrap work just fine but AdminLTE is calling this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at CardRefresh.js:18:30
    at adminlte.js:9:78
    at adminlte.js:10:3
```

In CardRefresh: `const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]`
In adminlte: `factory(global.adminlte = {}, global.jQuery));`

I tried rollup plugin-inject and purgecss, did not work.